# What can I do so that a column data can be displayed as a column and relate to the rest of the query?

Tags: sql

I am working on a SQL query where I relate several tables and one of them has the id field, and each id is linked to a characteristic example the id number "5" is the characteristic "antivirus". What I want is that all the data of the id number "5" has its own column and I can relate it with the rest of the data of the query.

This is the query that I have so far

```
SELECT 
    caracteristicas.nom_caracteristica,
    detalle_caracteristicas.id_caracteristica,
    quipos.serial,ubicacion.nom_ubicacion,
    sububicacion.nom_sububicacion 
FROM caracteristicas 
INNER JOIN detalle_caracteristicas ON caracteristicas.id_caracteristica=detalle_caracteristicas.id_caracteristica 
INNER JOIN equipos ON equipos.id_equipo=detalle_caracteristicas.id_equipo 
INNER JOIN ubicacion ON ubicacion.id_ubicacion=equipos.id_ubicacion 
INNER JOIN sububicacion ON equipos.id_sububicacion=sububicacion.id_sububicacion 
WHERE caracteristicas.id_caracteristica IN (5,6,7)
```

I don't know how close or far I am from what I am looking for.

Comment: Instead of explaining your tables, which is hard to parse, and sharing SQL that isn't working the way you want, which forces us to backwards engineer non-working code, please share your CREATE table statements, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Without a better description and sample data, this is a guess... perhaps you want a `case expression` such as `select case when id = '5' then 1 else 0 end as antivirus_flag...`

Comment: Sounds like you want a pivot or conditional aggregation, there should be a couple of questions already that has the answer

Comment: @RogerV. please do *not* readd conflicting tags and noise to posts; it is not helpful.

Comment: @ThomA not sure what you are referring to. Please be more specific.

Comment: Look at your [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77942419/revisions) @RogerV. . You re-add noise (like "Sorry, if you don't understand, my English is not very good.") and conflicting tags )[[tag:mysql]] and [[tag:sql-server]]).

Comment: @ThomA this is the original text of the post, I didn't add anything. Perhaps there was a simultaneous edit or some other bug.